# How can I bind an auto incremented column value of a database table to a textbox?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySql table in which I have a column named `payslip_no` which is set as an `AUTO_INCREMENT`. I want to set this auto incremented value to the value of a text box at the time of page load.

Another way is I am trying to increment this number programatically without setting the column as 'AUTO_INCREMENT'. Following is the code:

```
public void get_payslip_no()
{

int n1 =0;
try
{
rs2=st2.executeQuery("select max(payslip_no) from tbl_add_payroll");
if(rs2.next())
{
n1=rs2.getInt("payslip_no");
n1=n1+1;
String n2 = Integer.toString(n1);
txt_payslip_no.setText(n2);
System.out.println(n2);                   
}
}//try
catch(SQLException e2)
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Payroll-Serial no Storing Error!!!","Serial No Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);    
}//catch
}
```

This code is throwing A NullPointerException because the current database is null. How might I resolve this?

Comment: had u tried this code after filling one column manually inside database ..?

Comment: Can you please add the exception log here?

Comment: @ Dipen :- Its working if I add a one record manually.But its not feasible, I want to do it without adding record manually.

Comment: @ Sanjay:this is my exception log:-Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at dailyreport.Add_payroll.get_payslip_no(Add_payroll.java:597)
at dailyreport.Add_payroll.<init>(Add_payroll.java:44)
at dailyreport.Add_payroll$3.run(Add_payroll.java:497)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)

Comment: @Harshali check rs2 variable for null after executing query if(!rs2==null) perform all operations

Comment: in this case that exception will be throw first time only. When you will enter first data row..So in catch block rather then writing error log just print first payslip_no...

Comment: @JaiSoni= I did if(!rs2==null) ,its showing erron like 'bad operand type java.sql.ResultSet for unary operator '!''

Comment: @Harshali sorry this is correct syntax if(!rs2=null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this answer..:)

```
int no=101;
    int no1;
try
        {
           dbStatement = con.createStatement();
           dbResult= dbStatement.executeQuery("select payslip_no from tbl_add_payroll ORDER BY  payslip_no  DESC LIMIT 1");

          if(dbResult.next()==false)
          {
               jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(no));

          }
         else
          {         
            dbResult= dbStatement.executeQuery("select payslip_no from tbl_add_payroll ORDER BY payslip_no DESC LIMIT 1");      
                    while(dbResult.next())

                           {
                           deptno=dbResult.getInt("payslip_no");

                             }


                             no1=deptno+1;
                             jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(no1));
          }


     }catch(Exception E)
     {

     }
```